# How to retrieve search results from two fields in lucene index, giving one query?

Tags: search, lucene, indexing, field

Suppose I search for a query in Field A, and I want to retrive the corresponding fields B and C from my index, how should I go about it? I am using Lucene 3.6.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results of your query will be returned as a set of documents, not fields.  Once you've got a document, you can load whichever field contents you're interested in.

One thing that's probably worth watching out for is to ensure that your fields have been "stored".

Good luck,

Comment: Thankyou very much!is it possible toretrieve two fields with doc.get(field)?

Comment: You can keep asking a document for fields as much as you like.  Lazily loaded fields are only loaded as necessary (usually a very good thing) otherwise all the fields are loaded with the document and available as required.  Hope this helps,

Comment: thankyou so much. i realized i jus had to keep calling the get function...many thanks again!